# DAO getsession causes NullPointerException

Tags: java, hibernate, session

The code works on MyEclipse and return the correct DB set, but once I deploy it to Tomcat WebService, the system throws NullPointerException.

Strange thing is during the debug, when the system reaches

```
dao.getSession();
```

It jumpts to

```
session.close();
```

Then throws "java.lang.NullPointerException"

Here is the sample code:

```
try{
    exampleTableDAO dao = new exampleTableDAO();
    Session session = dao.getSession(); //When it reaches here
    /*****************/
    /*Other Codes*****/
    /*****************/

}catch(Exception e) {
    throw e;
} finally {
    session.close(); //Jumps here and throws error
}
```

After hours of reaserching, I still cannot find any hints on internet.

Comment: Show the code (at least constructor) of `exampleTableDao`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems your code is throwing some kind of exception.  However, you have unfortunately  written your code in such a way to make it difficult to find out what's going wrong when something does go wrong.

Firstly, `finally` blocks that perform cleanup should always check that the objects they are attempting to clean up were created in the first place.  If a `try` block tries to create an object, but fails and throws an exception, the `finally` block will still run, but it isn't going to able to clean up an object that was never created.

This is exactly what is happening in your code.  You're getting a NullPointerException because you're attempting to close a session when there isn't a session to close.

Worse still, an exception thrown out of a `finally` block *replaces* any previous exception that might have been thrown.  Whatever that was has been lost, and now you've got a NullPointerException instead.

So, before attempting to close anything in a `finally` block, *always check that it is not null*.

Secondly, there really is no point to your `catch` block.  All it achieves is obscuring where the real error is coming from.  I'd recommend simply deleting it.

The code fragment you have provided is unclear: it seems you might have a field named `session` in addition to the local variable also named `session` that you declare inside the `try` block.  (If you didn't have a field `session`, your code won't compile because the `session` local variable will be out of scope in the `finally` block.)

The next step is either to use the `session` field, if it exists:

```
try {
    exampleTableDAO dao = new exampleTableDAO();

    // Use field.
    session = dao.getSession();
    /*****************/
    /*Other Codes*****/
    /*****************/

} finally {
    // Check if field is null, and if not, close it.
    if (session != null) {
        session.close();
    }
}
```

or to use a local variable declared outside the `try` block:

```
Session session = null;
try {
    exampleTableDAO dao = new exampleTableDAO();

    // Use local variable.
    session = dao.getSession();
    /*****************/
    /*Other Codes*****/
    /*****************/

} finally {
    // Check if local variable is null, and if not, close it.
    if (session != null) {
        session.close();
    }
}
```

Your code will be unlikely to start working now, but it should at least be giving you a better idea of what's going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

is exampleTableDAO() return any object constructed using any external dependent object , which internally is not initialized?

Also you are rethrowing the exception , try to at least print the exception thrown.

Answer (score 0):

Since dao.getSession() drops to the finally clause, not the catch clause for Exception, dao.getSession() is throwing a RuntimeException. In the finally clause you're throwing a NullPointerException because you're trying to call session.close() and session is null (it never got initialized due to the first RuntimeException being thrown by dao.getSession).

The root cause of all this is likely your connection to your database is not initialized properly in your deployed application. No connection == lots of dao exceptions.